# How to save content form text editor to database in php and javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I designed a text editor using html and javaScript. Now I want to save the content written on text editor to be saved into the database.I want use php and jquery for that. But if therre is a simplier solution then I want to try that too. My database name is 'onlineexam', table name is 'question'. The field for the texeditor content is 'question'.  Here is my code in editor.php file -

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/889d5ab78b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <body onload="enableEditMode();" style="margin-top: 100px; margin-left: 200px;">
    <div>
    <select onclick="execCommandWithArg('fontName',this.value);">
    <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
    <option value="Comic Sans Ms">Comic Sans Ms</option>
    <option value="Courier">Courier</option>
    <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
    <option value="Times New Roman">Times New Roman</option>
    </select>
    <button onclick="execCmd('bold');"><i class="fas fa-bold"></i></button>
    <button onclick="execCmd('italic')"><i class="fas fa-italic"></i></button>
    <button onclick="execCmd('underline')"><i class="fas fa-underline"></i></button>

    <select onclick="execCommandWithArg('formatBlock',this.value);">
    <option value=H1>H1</option>
    <option value=H2>H2</option>
    <option value=H3>H3</option>
    <option value=H4>H4</option>
    <option value=H5>H5</option>
    </select>

    Size <select onclick="execCommandWithArg('fontSize',this.value);">
    <option value=1>1</option>
    <option value=2>2</option>
    <option value=3>3</option>
    <option value=4>4</option>
    <option value=5>5</option>
    </select>

    <button onclick="execCmd('justifyFull')"><i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i></button>
    <button onclick="execCmd('justifyRight')"><i class="fas fa-align-right"></i></button>
    <button onclick="execCmd('justifyCenter')"><i class="fas fa-align-center"></i></button>
    <button onclick="execCmd('justifyLeft')"><i class="fas fa-align-left"></i></button>
    <br><br>
    <button onclick="execCmd('subscript')"><i class="fas fa-subscript"></i></button>
    <button onclick="execCmd('superscript')"><i class="fas fa-superscript"></i></button>


    <button onclick="execCmd('insertOrderedList')"><i class="fas fa-list-ol"></i></button>
    Font Color <input type="color" onchange="execCommandWithArg('foreColor', this.value);">
    Highlighter <input type="color" onchange="execCommandWithArg('hiliteColor', this.value);">
    <button onclick="execCommandWithArg('insertImage', prompt('Enter URL:', ''));"><i class="fas fa- 
    image"></i></button>



    </div><br>
    <form action="database.php" method="post">
    <div class="form form-control">
    <label for="course_id">Course Id</label> 
    <input type="number" name="course_id">
    </div>
    <div class="form form-control"> 
    <label for="question"></label>
    <input type="hidden" name="question" id="question" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form form-control"> 
    <label form="exam_date"></label>
    <input type="date" name="exam_date">
    </div>

    <div class="form form-control"> 
    <input type="submit" value="post" name="submit">
    </div>
    </form>

    <iframe name="uzma" id="uzma" style="width: 500px; height: 250px;"></iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function enableEditMode(){
    uzma.document.designMode ='On';


    }
    function execCmd(command){

    uzma.document.execCommand(command, false, null);
    }
    function execCommandWithArg(command, arg){

    uzma.document.execCommand(command, false, arg);
    }



    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: there are many text editor libraries e.g. ckeditor, quill.js etc. which will save you time implementing it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Saving to a database would require server-side code. To request running server-side code on the client-side, you need an API. Here's an example of a very simple one you could use: (let's call this file `api.php`)

```php
if (isset($_POST['question'])) {
    $conn = new mysqli('address', 'user', 'password', 'database'); // init a db connection
    $sql = "INSERT into question (question) VALUES (?)"; //enter your MySQL query here. Where you need the data from the text editor, replace with a "?"
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); // prepare statement
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['question']); //assign variable to the "?" placeholder
    $stmt->execute(); //run the MySQL query
}
```

On your client-side:

```js
function saveToDB (question) {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", '/api.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { // Call a function when the state changes.
        if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
            // Request finished. Do processing here.
        }
    }
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("question", question); //add a field named `question` (received as $_POST['question'] in your PHP
    xhr.send(new URLSearchParams(formData).toString()); //encode formData and send the request
}
```

[XMLHttpRequest (xhr)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)
[PHP Prepared Statements (stmt)](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)

Please note that when building a public API, you might want to use some sort of [rate limiter](https://github.com/GSRV-io/ratelimiter/), have your API return data whether the execution was successful, etc.

Comment: I inserted the data with your code. Previously I used another code, that also inserts data. But the issue here is the data is saved as -> [object HTMLIFrameElement]. When I used select statement to show it, it shows -> [object HTMLIFrameElement]. I could not save and show the original content . Before implementing the client side code, I used the following code to pass content from iframe to input field. Here is the code -                                             
             document.getElementById('question').value = document.getElementById('uzma');

Comment: @AmatulUzma my function wants the content as a string/text. It looks like you have provided an HTML element/node instead. I do not know what your text editor is, but there usually is a method to fetch the text as a string, and you should use that. You can test the function by running `saveToDB("hello world")` in the browser console and it should insert a row with that value.